# How can we scroll items inside a div with Touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a code snippet which will allow the user to scroll the items inside a div. Its more of a spinning wheel / slot machine. I know an [existing solution for iPhone / iPod](http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch), but I wanted to have a simple stripped down code.

I have not used any images, and I believe this would involve CSS3 animations.
So far [here](http://jsbin.com/ahokof/3) is my code in jsbin. I have tried binding the `touchmove` event using jquery, but the alert is not popping up?

My main aim is to enable the user to scroll / swipe Up & down the items inside the div, without making the page scroll up and down. Any suggestion / edits to the code are appreciated.

My intended use for this is for mobile devices (iPhone / Android)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've almost been on the right side:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4
try iScroll.

only limitation that i encountered during my test was that you have to wrap your code in a list (ul) - though that could have been my bad

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to iScroll, it really helped. Do you  have any idea as to how can we make the `li` elements automatically start scrolling from down -> top when the `ul` finished? I mean like continuous scrolling from top -> bottom OR bottom -> top, as I see that `iScroll` limits the scrolling to the boundaries only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - I thought I did but then I came to the iScroll part ;) could you rephrase it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. My question is: Can we somehow make the `li` elements to scroll in a vertically circular manner, i.e. If we keep scrolling upwards, the after we reach the last item, the first items will immediately show up, and it continues in this fashion.. Any suggestions?

Comment: hm not right now - you should open up a new question for that. apart from that, google for "css3 infinite slideshow" - that seems to return some useful results

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved by simply using the deafult behavior on IOS Safari (iPhone/iPad)

Just give some fixed height to the container div with overflow
e.g.

```
<div id="container" style="height:400px;overflow:auto">
Your content
</div>
```

It would scroll using 2-fingers on versions prior to IOS5 and with a single-finger move for IOS5 and later..

Comment: unfortunately not... that's why there is something like iScroll.